# Is there an easy way to read filenames in a directory and add to an array?

Tags: php, arrays, directory

I have a directory: `Audio/`  and in that will be mp3 files only.  I'm wanting to automate the process of creating links to those files.  Is there a way to read a directory and add filenames within that directory to an array?

It'd be doubly cool if we could do an associative array, and have the key be the file name minus the .mp3 tag.

Any ideas?

To elaborate: I actual have several `Audio/` folders and each folder contains mp3s of a different event.  The event details are being pulled from a database and populating a table.  That's why I'm duplicating code, because right now in each `Audio/` folder, I'm having to define the filenames for the download links and define the filenames for the mp3 player.

Thank you!  This will greatly simplify my code as right now I'm repeating tons of code over and over!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SPL way is with [DirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php):

```
$files = array();
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('/path/to/files/') as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot() || !$fileInfo->isFile()) continue;
    $files[] = $fileInfo->getFilename();
}
```

Comment: I like this way even better!  You missed the $ on files[]

Answer (score 3):

And for completeness : you could use [glob](http://www.php.net/glob) as well :

```
$files = array_filter(glob('/path/to/files/*'), 'is_file');
```

This will return all files (but not the folders), you can adapt it as needed.

To get just the filenames (instead of files with complete path), just add :

```
$files = array_map('basename', $files);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes: use [`scandir()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php). If you just want the name of the file without the extension, use [`basename()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) on each element in the array you received from `scandir()`.

Answer (score 1):

This should be able to do what you're looking for:

```
// Read files
$files = scandir($dirName);
// Filter out non-files ('.' or '..')
$files = array_filter($files, 'is_file');
// Create associative array ('filename' => 'filename.mp3')
$files = array_combine(array_map('basename', $files), $files);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure...I think this should work...

```
$files[] = array();
$dir = opendir("/path/to/Audio") or die("Unable to open folder");
    while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
        $cleanfile = basename($file);
        $files[$cleanfile] = $file;
    }
    closedir($dir);
```

I imagine that should work...

Answer (score 1):

```
$results = array();
$handler = opendir($directory);
while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
  if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
    $results[] = $file;
  }
}
closedir($handler);
```

this should work, if you want any files to be excluded from the array, just add them to the if statement, same for file extensions