# How to get files in a directory and save it in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, image

From the question [Is there an easy way to read filenames in a directory and add to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509378/is-there-an-easy-way-to-read-filenames-in-a-directory-and-add-to-an-array/3509418#3509418), I have different files stored in a directory. now i want to get the .jpg files and put it in an array so i can sort the array according to time and display the images. I want to get the jpeg files that has the filename like

(datehere)-img_gen.jpg. 
ie. 
20131027123001-img-gen.jpg
20131030123102-img-gen.jpg

how can I do this in PHP? can anyone help me the right step by step code to do this?

I have this code but it's not working for me.

```
$ignore = array("..",".");
$dir = opendir("/home3/site/public_html/Master/uploader/uploader/");
$images = array();
$sortedimages = array();

//List files in images directory
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false)
    if (!in_array($file, $ignore))
        $images[] = $file;

foreach ($images as $image) {
    $filetime = filemtime("uploader/$image");
    $sortedimages[] = $filetime;
}

krsort($sortedimages);

foreach ($sortedimages as $sorted) {
    echo "$sorted<br/>";
}

closedir($dir);
```

it's just giving me gateway timeout. so i think i really need to get some better working code than this

please feel free to edit my code or give me some codes. thanks in advance :)

Comment: using `glob()` will mke it even easier... [see php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for answering :) can you give me some sample code on how can i use glob()? thanks again

Comment: @ExpertSyStem thanks for editing my code. i tried it but its returning the error 504 Gateway Timeout. what do you think is the problem here? thanks

Comment: @JbenKaye Please try my code if you haven't tried it yet. Does it work?

Comment: @JbenKaye: I did not edit your code (in the sense that I changed anything so that it works). One should never do that is SO (they should post an answer instead). I just improved it's formatting, so it could be easier for people to read it and spot possible problems. ComFreek seems to be knowing what it's talking about, so try out its suggestion and report back with any problems (if any).

Comment: thanks @ExpertSystem :) yes i'm trying his code. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Use [glob()](http://php.net/glob) and [usort()](http://php.net/usort):

```
$dir = './';
$files = glob($dir . '*.jpg');

usort($files, function ($file1, $file2) use ($dir) {
  $f1 = filemtime($dir . $file1);
  $f2 = filemtime($dir . $file2);

  if ($f1 == $f2) {
    return 0;
  }
  return ($f1 < $f2) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: thanks @ComFreek. i tried it but it's not displaying anything

i made $dir = './upload/';
what else do you think we can do with this? thanks again

Comment: I tried your code as it is but it's not displaying anything. i also tried doing like $dir = './uploader/upload'; and $dir = '/home3/site/public_html/Master/uploader/upload'; but still not displaying anything? what am i doing wrong? hope you can help me firther. thanks

Comment: @JbenKaye Why should my code display anything? It does not use `echo` or `print`. It just prepares a sorted array of filenames for you. Do whatever you want with `$files` after my code snippet.

Comment: now I realized. thanks. how can i test if it ? i tried to echo $files but it prints "Array". thanks. Also, how can i sort out only the files with the names like 20131030123102-img-gen.jpg? thank you again

Comment: @JbenKaye Try `var_dump($files)` and it will dump all entries. Do you only want files with such a filename pattern?

Comment: yes I only want files with such name pattern. CAn you show me how to use var_dump($files)? How exactly it works? thanks